# how to use facebook login in nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, rest, authentication, facebook-graph-api

I have been working on a web application which has angular on **frontend** and **nodejs** on the backend.
frontend uses facebook login button (js-sdk) and fetches user data(using graph API).
At the same time, nodejs has some rest Apis.I am trying to add authentication to rest APIs. I read about passport-facebook. I tried implementing it.

But the problem is when user click on login button in the UI (facebook login page is coming where the user is able to login into facebook). After that, if I tried to access to any of the node API still it is redirecting to login page.

Is there any way to avoid this scenario?
Is there any another way to add authentication to rest APIS (without password)?

Thanks in advance.and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check out my [tutorial](https://codeburst.io/node-js-rest-api-facebook-login-121114ee04d8) that is written having your usecase in mind.

`passport-facebook` is not appropriate for use when you are creating REST API. In that usecase it is much better to use `passport-facebook-token`. At least this is my experiance. `passport-facebook-token` can be found [here](https://github.com/drudge/passport-facebook-token).

When user finish with login with Facebook, your Node.js backend should create token that is used to identify user. And after that whenever user tries to access data from REST API, through your Angular.js app, it should send that token. Token is not something that Facebook is giving to your application, it is something that your application is creating when user is logged in.